# ecplise publish my web app (spring) in strange way cause 404 not found

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm new to tomcat with ecplise, i download some sample project (spring) somewhere on internet, i imported a project using ecplise, and i right click the server name on server tab, and select publish, the ecplise published my web app in this way

```
C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\spring4\ROOT
C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\spring4\spring-web-gradle-xml
                                                     \resource
                                                     \WEB-INF
```

if i run the web app in localhost:8080\spring4, it gives me 404 not found, i have to remove ROOT, and cut and paste the resource and WEB-INF to upper folder, and remove the spring-web-gradle-xml to get the webapp work, any one can help?

Comment: I think you imported the project from spring4 dir instead import from spring-web-gradle-xml dir

Comment: no, i import project from C:\xampp\tomcat\project\spring4-mvc-gradle-xml

Comment: check what context root you have in "Web Project Settings" under project's Properties.

Comment: checked, its "spring4"

Comment: you need to change it to spring-web-gradle-xml

Comment: I changed the Deploy path to C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps and the context root to / , seems ok now

Comment: great....glad it worked